# Replace NULL value with previous not null one within given partition

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2019

How to calculate new column where `NULL` values from `Number` column will be replaced with previous not null one? Not `NULL` ones shall stay untouched. All within partition of `Customer`.

```
+----------+------------+--------+
| Customer |    Date    | Number |
+----------+------------+--------+
| A        | 2016-01-01 | 9,00   |
| A        | 2020-01-01 | NULL   |
| A        | 2020-01-15 | 10,00  |
| A        | 2020-02-01 | NULL   |
| A        | 2020-03-01 | NULL   |
| A        | 2020-03-15 | 11,00  |
| A        | 2020-04-01 | NULL   |
| B        | 2016-01-01 | 9,00   |
| B        | 2020-01-01 | NULL   |
| B        | 2020-01-15 | 10,00  |
| B        | 2020-02-01 | NULL   |
| B        | 2020-03-01 | NULL   |
| B        | 2020-03-15 | 11,00  |
| B        | 2020-04-01 | NULL   |
+----------+------------+--------+
```

Assumptions:

- input data is `ORDER BY Customer, Date`, same is expected for the output
- the first row (oldest one) for each `Customer` will always have `Number` different from `NULL`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be easier if SQL Server supported `lag(ignore nulls)`. But it doesn't.  You can define groups by doing a cumulative count of the rows with values and then spreading those values:

```
select t.*,
       max(number) over (partition by customer, grp)
from (select t.*, count(number) over (partition by customer order by date) as grp
      from t
     ) t;
```

You can also do this with `apply`, but I suspect the above is faster under almost all circumstances.

Answer (score 1):

```
    SELECT customer ,[date] ,case when number is null then B.number else t.number end number
    FROM yourTable t
    CROSS APPLY (
        SELECT TOP 1 number
        FROM yourTable
        WHERE customer = t.customer
            AND number IS NOT NULL
        ORDER BY DATE DESC
        ) B
```

Comment: This also works, but the one with OVER is easier to incorporate into my query, which have been simplified here.